# Best way to initialize DB script while building docker image

Tags: mysql, dockerfile

I am building a docker machine using the image "mysql". I have some setup script to run for the first time the machine is built. This setup script will create some database and dabase users with specified permmissions.

**Following are the minimized version of my files..**

*pcdb1.entrypoint.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

mysql -uroot -p'pass123' -e 'show databases MYENTRYDB;'
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY ./pcdb1.entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/pcdb1.entrypoint.sh"];
```

I am getting the following error in the log

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>
> pcdb1 exited with code 1

What I understood is, my script is trying to run before mysql is started. But I am not sure how to do it properly. Can I get a suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

## EDIT: 20181007

I have found the way you mentioned in question--initialize DB while building docker image. But with a little difference, the way I found seems like initializing DB while running a container from image, although the initializing script was specified while building the image.

According to the official [information about mysql:5.7](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), there is paragraph named "Initializing a fresh instance". We could just add a initializing script into the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, the default `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` of image mysql:5.7 would execute it after database start-up.

For example:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY init-database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

content of init-database.sql:

```
create database light;
create user 'light'@'%' identified by 'abc123';
grant all privileges on light.* to 'light'@'%' identified by 'abc123';
grant all privileges on light.* to 'light'@'localhost' identified by 'abc123';
```

Build new image:

```
docker build -t light/mysql:5.7 .
```

Run a container:

```
docker run -tid --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' light/mysql:5.7
```

Examine initialization:

```
docker run -ti mysql /bin/bash
root@25e73d40c4ff:/# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: (abc123)
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. 
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql> show databases;
```

All work well.

### Former answer below.

## How to start mysql damon in container?

First of all, you are right on "trying to run before mysql is started" part. But still, there is a missing on "how MySQL starts exactly". If you execute `docker history mysql:5.7 --no-trunc`, you could see three important records among output like below:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["mysqld"]
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
/bin/sh -c ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
```

So far we should know when we start a mysql container with command below, the exact initial command in container is `docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld`.

```
docker run -tid -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' mysql:5.7
```

## How to initiate mysql in container?

Secondly, let's now have a check on `docker-entrypoint.sh` script.
There is a specific line like below, just at roughly middle position of this script, which means to start mysql daemon.

```
mysql=( mysql --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost --socket="${SOCKET}" )
```

After starting mysql, we could see lots of initiating statements in `docker-entrypoint.sh` script. Such as creating root user with password or not, granting privileges to root, creating database declared by users with `MYSQL_DATABASE` env and so on.

## Now here are solutions offered for you.

### Self-defining the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script.

In this way, you could whatever you want which is legal in mysql.

1. Get the whole entrypoint.sh script on your host.
2. Add your self-definition of mysql in the script, make your
   self-defining content at the bottom of this script. I assume you
   don't want to mess it with original content.
3. Build a new mysql image for your own with command and Dockerfile below.

   command: docker build -t mysql:self .
   Dockerfile:
   FROM mysql:5.7
   COPY /path/to/your-entrypoint.sh /
   ENTRYPOINT ["/your-entrypoint.sh"]
   CMD ["mysqld"]
4. If your don't want a new image, there is another way to change
   `ENTRYPOINT` when you run a container. But still, you should make your own script available in container.
   docker run -tid -v /path/to/your-entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' mysql:5.7

### Using default ENVs provided by mysql:5.7

In this way, there is a limit, especially on "specified permmissions" you mentioned.
The ENVs you need are: `MYSQL_DATABASE`, `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD`.
The command should like this:

```
docker run -tid -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' -e MYSQL_DATABASE='apps' -e MYSQL_USER='light' -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='abc123' mysql:5.7
```

This means that the database `apps` and user `light` will be created automatically, and the user `light` will be granted superuser permissions for the database `apps`.

More reference [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) on hub.docker.com.

Comment: The mysql:5.7 image already has it's own Docker file and entrypoint script with which it will build the image, start mysql and initialize it. Isn't there any way that I can add my own initialization script on top of it while I am building a new docker machine? For your information I am using docker-compose to create my machines. Becuase this has some customer script, I am pointing to my own dockerfile from the docker-compose.yml

Comment: @BlueBird As you said, there is already a n entrypoint for mysql:5.7. You want custom init script, so you modify it or you replace it. As I know, it seems no other way. Maybe there is or maybe not.

Comment: @BlueBird I've updated answer, is that what you want?

Comment: Note that if: 1.) you place a sql script into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and 2.) you have a volume mounted for db persistence, then the volume must be deleted as well.

Comment: I am just mounting the sql as volume (in docker-compose.yml) as suggested in 1.) and it works fine.
It also works with mysql 5.6