# Init postgres db with docker from server

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a node js server that runs in docker, but I want to initialize its db that depends of when initializes the either the server or the container.

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app/PhraseMicroservice
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8012
RUN npm install
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
COPY ./sql/dump_22092023.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I have this in the server docker file, but it doesn't work.In the docker compose I have the following:

```
phrase-db:
    container_name: phrasedb
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB_NAME=phrasedb
    ports:
        - '5480:5432'
    volumes: 
        - db_phrase:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./PhraseMicroservice/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Comment: Hi there! maybe this could help ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535725/best-way-to-initialize-db-script-while-building-docker-image

sql file should reside in the DB container image not in the service container, maybe a entrypoint script would be a best way to implement the initialization procedure, cheers!

Comment: Do you have some sort of database migration system?  It might be better to include migrations in your application container and not the database container, and optionally to run migrations automatically on startup.

Answer (score 0):

volumes:

- db_phrase:/var/lib/postgresql/data
- ./PhraseMicroservice/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  use the following commands for it.